# An excercise problem on Hoffman Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb R$ of all functions $f :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$, then identify if the following is a subspace of $V$:

> All $f \in V$ such that $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$

While I know that there is a theorem saying that if for any elements $\alpha ,\beta \in W$, and $\forall c \in F$, $c\alpha+\beta \in W$, then $W$ is a subspace. For this problem I find myself uncertain what is $\alpha, \beta$.

I guess I need to use the theorem to prove the result, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. Who is $V$, who is $x$ (you mean for any $x$)?

Comment: V is a vector space as stated, and it is over R so x is any real number

Comment: you say that $V$ is a vector space over $R$ and then you asked if a subset of functions is a subspace. Then my guess is that $V$ itself is the vector space of all functions from $R$ to itself.

Comment: Okay I've edited it and thanks for the feedback

Comment: In general $f(x^2)+g(x^2)\neq (f+g)(x)^2$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$W=\{ f(x)\in V : f(x^{2})=(f(x))^{2} \ \forall  x\in \mathbb R\}.$$

$W$ is not a subspace over $\mathbb R$. Because

$$(\alpha f_{1}(x)+ \beta f_{2}(x))^2 \neq \alpha f_{1}(x^{2})+ \beta f_{2}(x^{2}) $$

does not holds for all $f_1, f_2 \in W$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$. To see this, consider the functions

$f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_2(x) = x\in W$. Then define

$$f_{3}(x) := f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)=1+x,$$

$$\Rightarrow f_{3}(x^{2})=1+x^{2} \neq (1+x)^{2}=(f_{3}(x))^{2}.$$

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks!